# mathbb not working and mathbbm/mathds not compiling in rmarkdown

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the math 1 character in an rmarkdown file. `\mathbb{1}` just produces a simple `1`, and `\mathbbm{1}` / `\mathds{1}` does not compile for some reason.

```
title: "A3"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{mathtools}
  - \DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
  - \usepackage{dsfont}
output: 
  html_document
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I can’t tell for sure unless you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this looks like you aren’t including the font package you want.

For new documents, I recommend you use the modern toolchain, with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package.  With this, `\mathbb{1}` works out of the box.  You can load any font you like as your `\mathbb` font with the `[range=bb]` option of `\setmathfont`.

If you need to use the legacy toolchain, the classic `\mathbb` command supports only capital letters.  However, some font packages, including `stix2`, enable `\mathbb{1}`.  The `\mathds` command is from `dsfont`.

It is also possible to load a double-struck font containing numbers as a symbol font and access its gliphs with `\DeclareMathSymbol`, or as a text font and wrap it in `\mbox` or `\text` to use in math mode.

If you’re converting to HTML in any case, you might try replacing `dsfont` with `amssymb`.